Hilbert's theorem on lemniscates proof
Is there an English exposition of the theorem of Hilbert stating that any planar Jordan curve can be approximated by a lemniscate in a suitable way? The result is from 1897.

Yes, there are English expositions. I recommend the potential theory approach, see e.g. the book Potential theory in the complex plane by T. Ransford, Theorem 5.5.8 p.158

There is also a recent paper which generalizes Hilbert's theorem:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2407.14610
and which is self-contained.
